# Replace innerhtml on form submit with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to have a form that asks the user their name, then welcomes them to the website with that name without redirecting to a different page or reloading. So basically replace a form with "Welcome NAME" after submit is clicked.

My code:

```html
<div id="welcomeText">
 <form onsubmit="changeText()" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
</div>
        
        <script>
            function changeText() {
            var name = document.getElementById(welcomeForm).fname.value;
            var welcome = "Welcome, " + name;
            document.getElementById("welcomeText").innerHTML = welcome;
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give a name to the form before trying to access it, something like this:

```
//create the name attribute for the form
<form onsubmit="changeText()" method="post" name="myForm">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
        function changeText() {
        //access myForm using document object
        var name = document.name.fname.value;
        var welcome = "Welcome, " + name;
        document.getElementById("welcomeText").innerHTML = welcome;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I must have taken out the "welcomeForm" id at some point.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="welcomeText">
 <form onsubmit="changeText()" method="post" id="welcomeForm">
  Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
</div>
        
        <script>
            function changeText() {
            var name = document.getElementById("welcomeForm").fname.value;
            var welcome = "Welcome, " + name;
            document.getElementById("welcomeText").innerHTML = welcome;
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="welcomeText">
        Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="name">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" onclick="changeText()" onsubmit="changeText()">

</div>

        <script>
            function changeText() {
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var welcome = "Welcome, " + name;
            document.getElementById("welcomeText").innerHTML = welcome;
            document.getElementById("name").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try this it will display "welcome user" and also make button and input disappear.  In this case you don't even need a form.  You can access the name directly from the input without ever submitting the form.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here we are:

```
<div id="welcomeText">
    <form id="myform" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>

<script>
  var form = document.getElementById("myform");
  form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // This will prevent submitting the form
    var name = form.fname.value;
    var welcome = "Welcome, " + name;
    document.getElementById("welcomeText").innerHTML = welcome;
  });
</script>
```